# Trouble with installing TeamViewer on Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: remote-desktop, ubuntu-mate, teamviewer

I have fought with trying to install Teamviewer for a few hours now. I've followed the instructions from their website, but there always ends up being some road block.

- In the case of installing Teamviewer 13, after installation, it doesn't open.
- In the case of installing Teamviewer 12, it opens and loads up, however it complains about how it can't connect to the teamviewer servers, and that I need to enter proxy information. I don't even use a proxy!

I don't *really* need teamviewer, but it would be very helpful to manage my web server remotely. If I could get it to work that would be fantastic! Thank you in advance!

Here is the output of `systemctl status teamviewerd.service`

```
● teamviewerd.service - TeamViewer remote control daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-01-02 11:46:26 CST; 18min ago
  Process: 25832 ExecStart=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25834 (teamviewerd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/teamviewerd.service
           └─25834 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d

Jan 02 11:46:26 OPTI-ACCESSBOX systemd[1]: Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon...
Jan 02 11:46:26 OPTI-ACCESSBOX systemd[1]: Started TeamViewer remote control daemon.
```

Output of `killall TeamViewer` ; `/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewer`

```
Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

Output of `lscpu | grep "sse2\|Model name"`

```
Model name:            AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3500+
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch vmmcall
```

Output of `tail -f ~/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles/*.log`

```
==> /home/ladmin/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles/startup.log <==
Init...
TeamViewer:        13.0.6634 - DEB
Profile:           /home/ladmin ()
Desktop:           DS: ''   XDG: 'MATE'
XServer TTY:       none

ok (info)

CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
ok (profile)
tail: /home/ladmin/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles/gui.log: file truncated

==> /home/ladmin/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles/gui.log <==
QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.

==> /home/ladmin/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles/TeamViewer13_Logfile.log <==
2018/01/02 14:08:55.932 29031 140552580746432 GX10   Logger started.
2018/01/02 14:08:55.942 29031 140552580746432 GX10   Found 0 core dump files ...
2018/01/02 14:08:55.946 29031 140552580746432 GX10   systemd: logind service available
2018/01/02 14:08:55.954 29031 140552580746432 GX10   systemd: New seat seat0 [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0, activeSession='c9', canGraphical=1, canTTY=1, canMultiSession=1]
2018/01/02 14:08:55.958 29031 140552580746432 GX10   LogindSessionInfo: New session LogindSessionInfo [id=c13 user=ladmin state=user active=1 reliable=1 infoId=3428698831] [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c13 TTY= seat= display=:10 vtnr=4294967295 owner=[SysUser: ladmin [uid=1000, gid=1000 home=/home/ladmin gecos=ladmin,,, shell=/bin/bash]] idle=0(0) active=1 type=x11 class=user state=closing timestamp=1514923671161558 service=xrdp-sesman defaultCG= leader=28698 audit=0 remote=0 rHost= rUser= killProc=0]
2018/01/02 14:08:55.962 29031 140552580746432 GX10   LogindSessionInfo: New session LogindSessionInfo [id=c9 user=ladmin state=user active=1 reliable=1 infoId=1343005331] [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c9 TTY= seat=seat0 display=:0 vtnr=7 owner=[SysUser: ladmin [uid=1000, gid=1000 home=/home/ladmin gecos=ladmin,,, shell=/bin/bash]] idle=1(1514916332379260) active=1 type=x11 class=user state=active timestamp=1514914334520575 service=lightdm defaultCG= leader=3354 audit=0 remote=0 rHost= rUser= killProc=0]
2018/01/02 14:08:55.966 29031 140552580746432 GX10   LogindSessionInfo: New session LogindSessionInfo [id=c12 user=ladmin state=user active=1 reliable=1 infoId=3143301721] [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c12 TTY= seat= display=:10 vtnr=4294967295 owner=[SysUser: ladmin [uid=1000, gid=1000 home=/home/ladmin gecos=ladmin,,, shell=/bin/bash]] idle=0(0) active=1 type=x11 class=user state=closing timestamp=1514923172226496 service=xrdp-sesman defaultCG= leader=27930 audit=0 remote=0 rHost= rUser= killProc=0]
2018/01/02 14:08:55.978 29031 140552580746432 GX10   SysSessionInfoManager: observing sessions from logind is marked as reliable
2018/01/02 14:08:55.978 29031 140552580746432 GX10   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by VT [priority: 2]
2018/01/02 14:08:55.978 29031 140552580746432 GX10!  FrameBuffer: Cannot access /dev/fb0, frame buffer support unavailable
2018/01/02 14:08:55.987 29031 140552580746432 GX10   SysSessionInfoManager: own session cache set to '3428698831'
2018/01/02 14:08:55.987 29031 140552580746432 GX10   Running on Qt 5.5.1
2018/01/02 14:08:56.281 29031 140552580746432 GX10   GuiMain SM fallback: symbol not found
2018/01/02 14:08:56.282 29031 140552580746432 GX10   Initialised XRandR extension 1.1 (base=95 error=0)
2018/01/02 14:08:56.286 29031 140552580746432 GX10!! TL: ID 147 not found, Errorcode=11
2018/01/02 14:08:56.286 29031 140552580746432 GX10   : 1920x1080 (60 Hz)
2018/01/02 14:08:58.300 29031 140552580746432 GX10   Cannot acquire lock for "/home/ladmin/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles/gui.lock", reason: locked by other process (28561)
2018/01/02 14:08:58.324 29031 140552580746432 GX10   Shutting down System DBus
```

Output of `lspci | grep -i "VGA\|video"`

```
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C51 [GeForce 6150 LE] (rev a2)
```

(This is just the integrated graphics. There is no dedicated card. However, I do have one that I could use if needed.)

Output of `xrdnr -q`

```
 SZ:    Pixels          Physical       Refresh
*0   1920 x 1080   ( 508mm x 286mm )  *60  
Current rotation - normal
Current reflection - none
Rotations possible - normal 
Reflections possible - none
```

Output of `lspci -k | grep -i "VGA\|video" -A3`

```
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C51 [GeForce 6150 LE] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell C51 [GeForce 6150 LE]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

**The nightmare continues...**
I installed the right video drivers, to install Teamviewer on the server side. However, it would open up, but there would be no GUI, just border. So, I went to the computer where TV was working, to compare logs. But, it did the exact same thing the server was doing. So, I ran the logs on both of them, to see what was going on. But, I don't quite understand what it's trying to tell me. **NOTE: They still both have the FrameBuffer issue, even after properly installing drivers.** Here is what I came up with:

- `Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":10.0"` (This is on both machines.)
- `QSGContext::initialize: depth buffer support missing, expect rendering errors
  QSGContext::initialize: stencil buffer support missing, expect rendering errors
  [xcb] Too much data requested from _XRead
  [xcb] This is most likely caused by a broken X extension library
  [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
  TeamViewer: ../../src/xcb_io.c:736: _XRead: Assertion '!xcb_xlib_too_much_data_requested' failed.'` (This is also on both machines.)
- `2018/01/02 18:11:34.218  2438 140078491348224 GX10!!!XFixes extension not found, Errorcode=11` (This only seems to appear on the machine that it was working on)

**EDIT:** I have just realized that I don't need to install teamviewer on the server side, because I can just used Remmina and Xrdp. But I still don't have teamviewer on the non-server side working at the moment.

Comment: Have you considered using a web interface for your server

Comment: Did you install the [Teamviewer 13 .deb file](https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb) (teamviewer_13.0.6634_amd64.deb)?

Comment: Yes I did, it installs though Package installer and everything seems fine. However it does not open when I try to open it though the menu. And to answer Panthers question: The actual web site program (WordPress in this case) will be managed through a web interface. But if I have to change something directly, like an apache2 or mysql thing, It would be more direct to do it straight from the computer though Teamviewer.

Comment: If you get a teamviewer screen which does not show your own password, the cause is probably that teamviewerd did not start. Try `sudo /etc/init.d/teamviewerd restart` and then start the teamviewer application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are doing something wrong.

1. Download official deb-package

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install it with `gdebi` (`sudo apt-get install gdebi`)

   ```
   sudo gdebi-gtk ~/Downloads/teamviewer_*.deb
   ```

   or with `apt-get`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ~/Downloads/teamviewer_*.deb
   ```
3. Launch TeamViewer from *Applications|Internet|TeamViewer 13*, accept license and use it.
4. Set TeamViewer auto-launch from *Extras* menu, *Options*, *General* tab, check *Start TeamViewer with system* and set password for unattended access on *Security* tab, click *OK*.
5. Check status of teamviewerd service (should be `Active: active (running)`):

   ```
   systemctl status teamviewerd.service
   ```

**Notes:**

- TeamViewer may be launched from terminal with `/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer`
- TeamViewer GUI may be killed with `killall TeamViewer`
- TeamViewer expects that CPU supports SSE2 (`CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes` in its output)
- log-files are located at `~/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles`, one can watch them with `tail -f ~/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles/*.log`
- profile may be cleared with `rm -rf ~/.local/share/teamviewer13 ~/.config/teamviewer`.
- Log analysis shown that problems were xrandr (see `QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr`) and framebuffer (see `GX10! FrameBuffer: Cannot access /dev/fb0, frame buffer support unavailable line`). These problems were fixed by switching from *nouveau* to *nvidia-304*.

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't seem like it wants to open. I uninstalled the old version, and did this. I can tell its at least open somehow, because its in System Monitor. But it says its "sleeping" and its "Waiting Channel" is futex_wait_que_me.

Comment: Try to remove its folders with `rm -rf ~/.local/share/teamviewer13 ~/.config/teamviewer`. What is the output of `systemctl status teamviewerd.service` (add output to your question).

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: So the service is working normally. On my system GUI starts normally. Try to kill it with `killall TeamViewer` and launch again with `/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer`.

Comment: On TeamViewer launch it outputs interesting line `CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes`. What is the output of `killall TeamViewer ; /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer` on your machine (add to your question)? Which CPU do you have? Add output of `lscpu | grep "sse2\|Model name"` to the question.

Comment: After doing the `/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer` it says that its launching the GUI, but it hangs there for a little before going back to the thing where you enter commands (as you can tell, i dont know what thats called 0_o) But it never actually opens a gui.

Comment: Try the following: reboot system, open terminal and enter command for log-monitoring - `tail -f ~/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles/*.log` and then launch TeamViewer from menu or from terminal. And add log output to the question.

Comment: It seems that real problems are xrandr (see `QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr`) and framebuffer (see `GX10!  FrameBuffer: Cannot access /dev/fb0, frame buffer support unavailable` line). Which video card do you have (update your question with output of  `lspci | grep -i "VGA\|video"`)? What is the output of `xrandr -q`?

Comment: It also needed to know which video driver is in use: `lspci -k | grep -i "VGA\|video" -A3`.

Comment: Nouveau driver works poor. So, I think next step will be installation of proprietary nvidia driver. I hope it will help to solve TeamViewer problem. Try to use search on this site for complete instruction. You need nvidia 304, not newer.

Comment: That worked! I thought it wasn't going to open up, but it did! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. It was a great quest :)

Comment: Another thing, I just tried to install teamviewer on the server end. I already installed the nvidia driver. It opens up with the terms of service, but doesn't really render, like there is no gui just the border. Then it closes. However, opening it up in terminal, it says "Aborted (core dumped)" What does that exactly mean? Do I need to open up another discussion for this?

Comment: Try to debug the issue in the way we discussed here (logs, lscpi, xrandr, framebuffer and so on). In case of problems you can ask another question, I think. The server may have other hardware (at least video card and/or CPU).

Comment: I added some things to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71102/discussion-between-apt-get-install-cat-and-n0rbert).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, it is now basically a mute point since I ended up using Chrome Remote Desktop, since it requires almost no installation at all other than a host program which installed perfectly on both linux machines. However, if for some reason you are still determined, or want the challenge to fix my "TeamViewer Nightmare" be my guest. :D I will still give out any outputs of commands if you want them. Thank you for all of your help guys!